# execute() in Expression class

Tags: java, reflection, applet

The latest security breach in Java7, where a applet can execute untrusted code on users machine. More information is available at http://www.h-online.com/security/features/The-new-Java-0day-examined-1677789.html.

But the question I have is: It is mentioned that all this is possible due to the execute() method introduced in Expression class. But there is nothing special that it does, which was not possible in previous versions. Here is the source:

```
 @Override
public void execute() throws Exception {
    setValue(invoke());
}
```

and for getValue() which exists since java1.4:

```
 public Object getValue() throws Exception {
    if (value == unbound) {
        setValue(invoke());
    }
    return value;
}
```

getValue() does everything that execute() does. Then why so much fuss about the execute method??

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely, the exploit code also calls `.getValue()`. Clearly, the vulnerability lies within `invoke`. `execute` is essentially a public interface to call the private `invoke`.

Comment: Yes true. so does getValue() and it existed much before java7. Question is why did it become famous with java7 only :)

Comment: @Jatin: doesn't java 6 have the same security flaw?

Comment: Yes that is what I am saying. It is just a confirmation.

Comment: but it doesn't work in Java6. The source looks simialar. I am unable to conclude the discussion here.

Answer (score 0):

I reported a bug several years ago where the access checking in Expression isn't identical to the compiler's. Possibly this is another example.